# When I run the .war file using tomcat 8.5.15 it got stuck

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, heroku, webapp-runner

I tried to run `.war` file using command `java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war` and I am using `maven`,  `webapp-runner` , `tomcat 8.5.15`, `oracle java 8` on `ubuntu 14.04` , When it says `Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]` it stuck and never ends

**My log**

```html
java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.warExpanding FitStepBot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war into /media/hussein/New Volume/newJava/FitStepBot/target/tomcat.8080/webapps/expanded
Adding Context  for /media/hussein/New Volume/newJava/FitStepBot/target/tomcat.8080/webapps/expanded
May 29, 2017 1:07:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 29, 2017 1:07:43 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 29, 2017 1:07:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
May 29, 2017 1:07:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
May 29, 2017 1:07:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
May 29, 2017 1:07:45 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 29, 2017 1:07:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

**My pom.xml**

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>FitStepBot</groupId>
<artifactId>FitStepBot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
 <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.1</version>
   <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
   <configuration>
    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
   </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3</version>
   <executions>
    <execution>
     <phase>package</phase>
     <goals>
      <goal>copy</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
      <artifactItems>
       <artifactItem>
        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.15.0</version>
        <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
       </artifactItem>
      </artifactItems>
     </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

---

Comment: is there a `web.xml` in your war? cause the log says it can't find it `INFO: No global web.xml found`